# Align h2 vertically bottom

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm learning html and css starting with basics. I'm coding some simple site. I have a problem regarding aligning h2 vertically to bottom.

What I want to achieve is the header with background image (height 240px) that has a black bar with text: "love cucumbers" aligned to  the bottom of it.
I've tried multiple solutions but they didn't work.

The text should be then "9 reasons why you should love cucumbers".

Here is relevant css and html:

```css
.body {
    clear: both;
    width: 800px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

header {
    height: 240px;
    margin: 1em auto 3em;
    background-image: url("https://media.mercola.com/ImageServer/Public/2014/August/cucumber-health-benefits-fb.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;

    font-family: 'Lobster', Georgia, Times, serif;
}

#caption {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;

    background: #191919;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;

    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;

    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
```

```html
<header class="body">
 <h2 id="caption">Love cucumbers <3</h2>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this using position relative for header and position absolute for h2. Please see the below updated code

```css
.body {
    clear: both;
    width: 800px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

header {
    height: 240px;
    margin: 1em auto 3em;
    background-image: url("https://media.mercola.com/ImageServer/Public/2014/August/cucumber-health-benefits-fb.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;

    font-family: 'Lobster', Georgia, Times, serif;
    position:relative;
}

#caption {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;

    background: #191919;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;

    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px; }
```

```html
<header class="body">
 <h2 id="caption">Love cucumbers <3</h2>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the line-height of the caption with the same height as the header like this.

```
#caption {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 240px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87wn5423/).

I basically added these properties to the `.body class`

```
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px; /* Edit this with as you wish */
```

And to the `#caption id`

```
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
```

PS: The background-image property does not work on `table-cell` elements, so i applied the background-image to the `body tag`.